# Why do I do Cmake .. and make?

Tags: bash, unix, makefile, cmake

I'm trying to install some programme on an Amazon Linux 2 distribution and for some reason, I've to compile a bunch of tools from source.

It was my understanding I should do:

```
cd my_source_code
./configure
make
make install
```

The intent would be:

- ./configure will check if I have all tools needed
- make: will compile the source files into binaries that I can then use
- make install: will place that said binaries in an accessible place

All of that tools ask me to do different stuff, for example:

```
./bootstrap
make
make install
```

or

```
./bootstrap.sh
./b2
./b2 install
```

or

```
cmake .
make
make install
```

I guess the `./boostrap` is just the `./configure` script with a different name. Is that right?

For the cmake, why do I have to do both cmake and make? Aren't they the same?

I a bit lost with all that possibilities.

Comment: this one https://prateekvjoshi.com/2014/02/01/cmake-vs-make/

Comment: What is it that you're being asked to compile with `cmake .`?

Comment: cmake writes configuring scripts and then build Make file for the project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `cmake .` is a configuration step and corresponds to `./configure` from Autotools. In result of running this command you get whatever build files you have requested - `Makefile`s of various sorts, Visual Studio projects, etc.

After that you need to actually build them. In case of `Makefile`s you run `make` and in case of Visual Studio you open it in the IDE and click "Build" (or run `msbuild`, if you want console).

CMake has `--build` flag to automatically invoke underlying build system, so you can also do

```
# configure
cmake .
# build
cmake --build .
```

Comment: how does cmake know the default build system? Is there a way for me to check what my default build system is? (other than taking an educated guess based on the OS) I am assuming that it is possible to have different build systems on the same OS is that true?

Comment: For Unix-like OSes the default is always "Makefiles". For windows it defaults to `NMake Makefiles`, IIRC.

Comment: What if you have multiple build systems, for example both Make and Ninja? Does CMake use the build system that ships with the operating system by default?

Comment: As I said, the default is makefiles, whatever other build systems are installed.

Comment: Right. I got that. My question is whether CMake makes a guess based on the OS or if it uses some systematic way to query the default build system. From CMake documentation:  "cmake --build command line will launch the underlying build system tool"
But it does not indicate how it determines the underlying build system tool (and it does not say that it is always makefiles).

Comment: @pooya13 ah, you're asking about `--build` flag. In this case it invokes the build system that was used for configuring. This command should be ran after configuring, inside the build directory.

Answer (score 3):

`CMake` is equivalent to running `./configure` but is `autoconf` and `automake` combined into a single program. It is `automake` which generates the Makefiles. `CMake` started on Windows and can not only generate Unix `Makefiles` but also `Visual Studio` projects and some other targets.

Make is very low level and doesn't directly support a recursive build that traverses a directory structure. `CMake` and `Automake` are Makefile generators that provide a higher level of abstraction and provide a mechanism to create a recursive build.

`./bootstrap` in general has the steps to create the `configure` script which is usually not in the git repo because it is generated. When a source tarball is created the `configure` script is included for convenience.